# Is it worth typesetting hand written notes?

Tags: phd, research-process

So I have about 10-15 hand written notes on various areas of my phd and they cover basically everything I’ve done in the last year or so of my project.

is it a good idea to maybe spend some time formatting these notes into a LaTeX/word processed document so that they’re presentable and can be copied over to Beamer slides etc?

Comment: I voted to close as opinion based. Do find some way to keep this material for possible future use. Whether that's typeset or not is a personal decision.

Comment: How fast do you type? How neat is your handwriting (have you tried OCR on it)? How about scan your notes to PDF and if you ever go back to them you type up what was important?

Comment: I recommend typing up your notes in LaTeX in order to use them as parts of your dissertation or a paper. It may be useful to include even more details in your typed notes than you intend to put in your thesis; the notes may come in handy 30 years from now when someone asks for details about some part of your work. Beamer slides should be much more succinct, consisting mainly of bullet points, not paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. More portable, more searchable, more copy-able, and... if suitably backed-up, far more stable and secure than paper (under any not-toooo-insane circumstances).